Bioavailability of plant food?
The kcal count of food is evaluated by either bomb calorimetry or mostly by determining macronutrient concentration and multiplying with their atwater factors.
I am interested in the bioavailable kcalories of plant food assuming that we cannot extract nutrients as efficiently from plant matrices.
We see in every plant based diet study that participants loose weight even if it is a calorie matched protocol.
Do you have a comparison or estimation between theoretical and real energy value of plants? Its not easy as it will vary significantly between individuals considering differences in microbiome and metabolizing enzymes.
.

you probably want to look up the effects of fiber on digestion, that will be the biggest effect.
